# Error installing module File::NFSLock with perl from conda

Tags: perl, conda

I installed perl from conda and fixed installation to be able to install modules via cpanm following instructions from: [Unable to install perl modules via cpanm in conda environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65724310/unable-to-install-perl-modules-via-cpanm-in-conda-environments/65728195?noredirect=1#comment116294238_65728195)

Unfortunately, I wasn't still able to properly install File::NFSLock module both with `cipanm` and manually (`perl Makefile.PL`) unless I use `--force --notest`. The problem is that tests fail with:

```
#   Failed test at t/300_bl_sh.t line 115.
Shared locks not running simultaneously at t/300_bl_sh.t line 116, <$rd3> line 18.
# Looks like your test exited with 4 just after 27.
t/300_bl_sh.t ..... Dubious, test returned 4 (wstat 1024, 0x400)
Failed 47/73 subtests
t/400_kill.t ...... ok
t/410_die.t ....... ok
t/420_crash.t ..... ok
t/430_taint.t ..... ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/300_bl_sh.t   (Wstat: 1024 Tests: 27 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  27
  Non-zero exit status: 4
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 73 tests but ran 27.
```

I'm working on an nfs4 filesystem. Can there be any possible issue in using this module in this filesystem even if some tests failed?

Comment: The module installs fine here (Ubuntu 20.04, ext4 filesystem). What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm working on virtualized server with CentOS Linux 7.8.2003. Perl is installed via conda on nfs4 filesystem.

Comment: The test failure concerns shared locks. If your main use case for file locking over NFS is exclusive locks, then go for it.

Comment: Thanks @mob. A linked problem is that an application (maker: https://www.yandell-lab.org/software/maker.html) that uses this module for locking mechanism, fails with the message:

`ERROR: The directory is locked.  Perhaps by an instance of MAKER.`

The application only works in my filesystem if it is run with `-nolock` flag. This application is developed to run also in a distributed manner on a computer cluster with mpi: `mpiexec -mca btl ^openib -n 4 maker -h`.

I think the cause could be lead to exclusive locks not working with (or without) that modules.

Comment: Just to be more precise, filesystem I was working on is OneFS from EMC Isilon exported to virtual server through nfs4 protocol.