# HTML-Parser distribution installing issue

Tags: perl, miniconda, lwp

I'm trying to install LWP::Simple, which has HTML-Parser as a dependency.

I was looking if my problem with the installation the HTML-Parser distribution module was resolved on any other posts but (at first glance) it seems to be nothing similar.

Here are the error messages that I got:

```
cpan[1]> install LWP::Simple 
Reading '/home/valentinignacio/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 22 Mar 2021 00:17:03 GMT
Running install for module 'LWP::Simple'
Checksum for /home/valentinignacio/.cpan/sources/authors/id/O/OA/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /home/valentinignacio/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring O/OA/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
HTTP::Status already exists in PREREQ_PM (at version 6.07) -- need to do a sane metamerge! at Makefile.PL line 159.
HTTP::Status already exists in FallbackPrereqs (at version 6.07) -- need to do a sane metamerge! at Makefile.PL line 162.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite HTML::Entities 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite HTML::HeadParser 0 not found.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for libwww::perl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
  /home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for O/OA/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----      OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz     ----
    HTML::Entities [requires]
    HTML::HeadParser [requires]
    Test::LeakTrace [build_requires,optional]
Running install for module 'HTML::Entities'
Checksum for /home/valentinignacio/.cpan/sources/authors/id/O/OA/OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz ok
Configuring O/OA/OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for HTML::Parser
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz
  /home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for O/OA/OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz
cp lib/HTML/HeadParser.pm blib/lib/HTML/HeadParser.pm
cp lib/HTML/Filter.pm blib/lib/HTML/Filter.pm
cp lib/HTML/Parser.pm blib/lib/HTML/Parser.pm
cp lib/HTML/PullParser.pm blib/lib/HTML/PullParser.pm
cp lib/HTML/Entities.pm blib/lib/HTML/Entities.pm
cp lib/HTML/TokeParser.pm blib/lib/HTML/TokeParser.pm
cp lib/HTML/LinkExtor.pm blib/lib/HTML/LinkExtor.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for Parser ()
chmod 644 "Parser.bs"
"/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Parser.bs blib/arch/auto/HTML/Parser/Parser.bs 644
"/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/perl" "/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/lib/5.32.0/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/lib/5.32.0/ExtUtils/typemap' -typemap '/home/valentinignacio/.cpan/build/HTML-Parser-3.76-4/typemap'  Parser.xs > Parser.xsc
mv Parser.xsc Parser.c
/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/..//bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gcc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE --sysroot=/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/..//x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2   -DVERSION=\"3.76\" -DXS_VERSION=\"3.76\" -fPIC --sysroot=/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/..//x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot "-I/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/lib/5.32.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"  -DMARKED_SECTION Parser.c
/bin/sh: 1: /home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/..//bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gcc: not found
make: *** [Makefile:358: Parser.o] Error 127
  OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
[continues]
```

This ultimately leads to a failure to install LWP::Simple.

```
[continued from above]
Running install for module 'HTML::HeadParser'
  OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /home/valentinignacio/.cpan/build/HTML-Parser-3.76-4
  OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
  OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz
  Could not make: Unknown error
  OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /home/valentinignacio/.cpan/build/libwww-perl-6.53-4
  OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running make for O/OA/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
Warning: Prerequisite 'HTML::Entities => 0' for 'OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz' failed when processing 'OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Warning: Prerequisite 'HTML::HeadParser => 0' for 'OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz' failed when processing 'OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----      OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz     ----
    Test::LeakTrace [build_requires,optional]
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/nntp.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/nntp.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/nogo.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/nogo.pm
cp lib/LWP/RobotUA.pm blib/lib/LWP/RobotUA.pm
cp lib/LWP/Debug.pm blib/lib/LWP/Debug.pm
cp lib/LWP/DebugFile.pm blib/lib/LWP/DebugFile.pm
cp lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm blib/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/ftp.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/ftp.pm
cp lib/LWP/Authen/Digest.pm blib/lib/LWP/Authen/Digest.pm
cp lib/LWP/Debug/TraceHTTP.pm blib/lib/LWP/Debug/TraceHTTP.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/cpan.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/cpan.pm
cp lib/LWP/Simple.pm blib/lib/LWP/Simple.pm
cp lwpcook.pod blib/lib/libwww/lwpcook.pod
cp lib/LWP/Authen/Ntlm.pm blib/lib/LWP/Authen/Ntlm.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/loopback.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/loopback.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/gopher.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/gopher.pm
cp lib/LWP/ConnCache.pm blib/lib/LWP/ConnCache.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/data.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/data.pm
cp lwptut.pod blib/lib/libwww/lwptut.pod
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/file.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/file.pm
cp lib/LWP/Authen/Basic.pm blib/lib/LWP/Authen/Basic.pm
cp lib/LWP/MemberMixin.pm blib/lib/LWP/MemberMixin.pm
cp lib/LWP.pm blib/lib/LWP.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/mailto.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/mailto.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm
cp bin/lwp-download blib/script/lwp-download
"/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/lwp-download
cp bin/lwp-dump blib/script/lwp-dump
"/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/lwp-dump
cp bin/lwp-mirror blib/script/lwp-mirror
"/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/lwp-mirror
cp bin/lwp-request blib/script/lwp-request
"/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/lwp-request
Manifying 4 pod documents
Manifying 11 pod documents
  OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
The current configuration of allow_installing_outdated_dists is 'ask/no', but for this option we would need 'CPAN::DistnameInfo' installed. Please install 'CPAN::DistnameInfo' as soon as possible. As long as we are not equipped with 'CPAN::DistnameInfo' this option does not take effect
Running make test for OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t t/base/*.t t/base/protocols/*.t t/leak/*.t t/local/*.t t/robot/*.t
t/00-report-prereqs.t .......... # 
# Versions for all modules listed in MYMETA.json (including optional ones):
# 
# === Configure Requires ===
# 
#     Module                       Want     Have
#     ------------------------ -------- --------
#     CPAN::Meta::Requirements 2.120620    2.140
#     ExtUtils::MakeMaker           any     7.44
#     File::Copy                    any     2.34
#     Getopt::Long                  any     2.51
#     Module::Metadata              any 1.000037
# 
# === Build Requires ===
# 
#     Module              Want Have
#     ------------------- ---- ----
#     ExtUtils::MakeMaker  any 7.44
# 
# === Test Requires ===
# 
#     Module                 Want     Have
#     ---------------------- ---- --------
#     ExtUtils::MakeMaker     any     7.44
#     File::Spec              any     3.78
#     FindBin                 any     1.51
#     HTTP::Daemon           6.12     6.12
#     Test::Fatal             any    0.016
#     Test::More             0.96 1.302175
#     Test::Needs             any 0.002006
#     Test::RequiresInternet  any     0.05
# 
# === Test Recommends ===
# 
#     Module              Want     Have
#     --------------- -------- --------
#     CPAN::Meta      2.120900 2.150010
#     Test::LeakTrace      any  missing
# 
# === Runtime Requires ===
# 
#     Module                Want    Have
#     --------------------- ---- -------
#     Digest::MD5            any 2.55_01
#     Encode                2.12    3.06
#     Encode::Locale         any    1.05
#     File::Listing            6    6.14
#     HTML::Entities         any missing
#     HTML::HeadParser       any missing
#     HTTP::Cookies            6    6.10
#     HTTP::Date               6    6.05
#     HTTP::Negotiate          6    6.01
#     HTTP::Request            6    6.29
#     HTTP::Request::Common    6    6.29
#     HTTP::Response           6    6.29
#     HTTP::Status          6.18    6.29
#     IO::Select             any    1.42
#     IO::Socket             any    1.43
#     LWP::MediaTypes          6    6.04
#     MIME::Base64           2.1    3.15
#     Net::FTP              2.58    3.11
#     Net::HTTP             6.18    6.21
#     Scalar::Util           any    1.55
#     Try::Tiny              any    0.30
#     URI                   1.10    5.09
#     URI::Escape            any    5.09
#     WWW::RobotRules          6    6.02
#     base                   any    2.27
#     strict                 any    1.11
#     warnings               any    1.47
# 
# === Runtime Suggests ===
# 
#     Module               Want    Have
#     -------------------- ---- -------
#     Authen::NTLM         1.02 missing
#     Data::Dump           1.13 missing
#     IO::Socket::INET      any    1.41
#     LWP::Protocol::https 6.02 missing
# 
# 
# *** WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING ***
t/00-report-prereqs.t .......... 1/1 # 
# The following REQUIRED prerequisites were not satisfied:
# 
# HTML::Entities is not installed (any version required)
# HTML::HeadParser is not installed (any version required)
# 
t/00-report-prereqs.t .......... ok   
t/10-attrs.t ................... ok   
t/base/default_content_type.t .. # Some tests for the PUT/PATCH methods can only be run on 
# HTTP::Request version 6.07/6.12 or higher.
# If your version isn't good enough, we'll skip those.
# Your version is 6.29 and that's good enough
t/base/default_content_type.t .. ok   
t/base/protocols.t ............. ok   
t/base/protocols/nntp.t ........ skipped: nntp.perl.org is unstable and Test::RequiresInternet is not catching it
t/base/proxy.t ................. ok   
t/base/simple.t ................ ok   
t/base/ua.t .................... 1/? 
#   Failed test '$res->header("Content-Style-Type", "text/css")'
#   at t/base/ua.t line 122.

#   Failed test '$res->header("Content-Script-Type", "text/javascript")'
#   at t/base/ua.t line 123.
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 51.
t/base/ua.t .................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 2/51 subtests 
t/base/ua_handlers.t ........... ok   
t/leak/no_leak.t ............... skipped: Need Test::LeakTrace
t/local/autoload-get.t ......... 1/4 
#   Failed test 'Response was successful'
#   at t/local/autoload-get.t line 26.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 4.
t/local/autoload-get.t ......... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/4 subtests 
t/local/autoload.t ............. 1/4 
#   Failed test 'Response was successful'
#   at t/local/autoload.t line 29.
# <html>
# <head><title>An Error Occurred</title></head>
# <body>
# <h1>An Error Occurred</h1>
# <p>500 Can't locate HTML/Entities.pm in @INC (you may need to install the HTML::Entities module) (@INC contains: /home/valentinignacio/.cpan/build/libwww-perl-6.53-4/blib/lib /home/valentinignacio/.cpan/build/libwww-perl-6.53-4/blib/arch /home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/lib/site_perl/5.32.0 /home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/lib/5.32.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/lib/5.32.0 .)</p>
# </body>
# </html>
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 4.
t/local/autoload.t ............. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/4 subtests 
t/local/get.t .................. ok   
t/local/http.t ................. 1/130 
#   Failed test 'get file: good title'
#   at t/local/http.t line 178.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'En pr�ve'

#   Failed test 'get file: good content'
#   at t/local/http.t line 179.
#                   ''
#     doesn't match '(?^u:� v�re)'

#   Failed test 'terminate: bye bye'
#   at t/local/http.t line 438.
#                   ''
#     doesn't match '(?^:Bye, bye)'
# Looks like you failed 3 tests of 130.
t/local/http.t ................. Dubious, test returned 3 (wstat 768, 0x300)
Failed 3/130 subtests 
t/local/httpsub.t .............. ok   
t/local/protosub.t ............. ok   
t/redirect.t ................... ok   
t/robot/ua-get.t ............... ok     
t/robot/ua.t ................... ok     

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/base/ua.t                  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 51 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  20-21
  Non-zero exit status: 2
t/local/autoload-get.t       (Wstat: 256 Tests: 4 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  4
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/local/autoload.t           (Wstat: 256 Tests: 4 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  4
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/local/http.t               (Wstat: 768 Tests: 130 Failed: 3)
  Failed tests:  37-38, 129
  Non-zero exit status: 3
Files=19, Tests=269, 17 wallclock secs ( 0.06 usr  0.03 sys +  1.64 cusr  0.20 csys =  1.93 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 4/19 test programs. 7/269 subtests failed.
make: *** [Makefile:1029: test_dynamic] Error 255
Lockfile removed.
  OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
2 dependencies missing (HTML::Entities,HTML::HeadParser); additionally test harness failed
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
Running install for module 'Test::LeakTrace'
Checksum for /home/valentinignacio/.cpan/sources/authors/id/L/LE/LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.17.tar.gz ok
Configuring L/LE/LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.17.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Test::LeakTrace
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.17.tar.gz
  /home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for L/LE/LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.17.tar.gz
cp lib/Test/LeakTrace/JA.pod blib/lib/Test/LeakTrace/JA.pod
cp lib/Test/LeakTrace.pm blib/lib/Test/LeakTrace.pm
cp lib/Test/LeakTrace/Script.pm blib/lib/Test/LeakTrace/Script.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for LeakTrace ()
chmod 644 "LeakTrace.bs"
"/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- LeakTrace.bs blib/arch/auto/Test/LeakTrace/LeakTrace.bs 644
"/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/perl" "/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/lib/5.32.0/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/lib/5.32.0/ExtUtils/typemap'  LeakTrace.xs > LeakTrace.xsc
mv LeakTrace.xsc LeakTrace.c
/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/..//bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gcc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE --sysroot=/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/..//x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.17\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.17\" -fPIC --sysroot=/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/..//x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot "-I/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/lib/5.32.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   LeakTrace.c
/bin/sh: 1: /home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/..//bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gcc: not found
make: *** [Makefile:340: LeakTrace.o] Error 127
  LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.17.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Running install for module 'Test::LeakTrace'
  LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.17.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /home/valentinignacio/.cpan/build/Test-LeakTrace-0.17-4
  LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.17.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
  LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.17.tar.gz
  Could not make: Unknown error

Failed during this command:
 OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz              : make NO
 OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz              : make_test NO 2 dependencies missing (HTML::Entities,HTML::HeadParser); additionally test harness failed
 (optional) LEEJO/Test-LeakTrace-0.17.tar.gz  : make NO
```

What can I do? I Tried to install manually the dependencies (Entities and HeadParser) but I got the next unknown errors for both:

```
cpan[3]> install HTML::Entities                                                 
Running install for module 'HTML::Entities'
  OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /home/valentinignacio/.cpan/build/HTML-Parser-3.76-4
  OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
  OALDERS/HTML-Parser-3.76.tar.gz
  Could not make: Unknown error
```

I'll be so thankful if you can help me with this :)

Comment: See also [How to make perl Makefile.PL use a given C compiler when compiling an XS module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65728942/2173773)

Comment: More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65724310/2173773)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the relevant line:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/..//bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gcc: not found
```

`perl` was built using a compiler found at `/home/valentinignacio/miniconda3/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gcc`, but it no longer exists at that location.<sup>[1]</sup> It is needed, so reinstall it.

---

Once this is rectified, run `cpan LWP::Simple` again. You may need to run the following command in `cpan` first:

```
o conf build_dir_reuse 0
o conf commit
```

This resets the `build_dir_reuse` setting back to its default value. The default value of this settings causes the "*Has already been unwrapped into directory*" and "*Has already been prepared*" checks to be avoided, forcing a sincere attempt to install the module even if a previous attempt failed.

---

1. Ok, technically, you copied the `perl` installation from another machine (by installing the appropriate package), but didn't copy over `gcc` (by installing the appropriate package). Potato potahto.